# Download Pictures from web using webBrowser control

Tags: vb6, browser

First excuse for my English i'm from spain.

I am a little worried because i cannot been able to finish my project in the school, I am trying to develop an application in visual basic 6 to discharge the cd covers (Album Art) from internet using the webbrowser control,  i put this path to navigate:

"http://www.google.com.co/search?
hl=es&safe=active&gbv=2&biw=1280&bih=821&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=%22heroes+del+silencio%22%2B%22avalancha%22%2Balbum+art+small&oq=%22heroes+del+silencio%22%2B%22avalancha%22%2Balbum+art+small&aq=f&aqi=&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl="

This display the covers that I am needing, but i'm trying to get the first Picture filename or URL and save this direct to a Folder In my Pc, please can some help to me, Thanks...

I will be very grateful for your help

Comment: @geovanny1974 if someone has spent time to answer your question, you could at least give them the time and thanks to accept it. Otherwise it seems like total disregard to the person who has helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a part of code and you can continue to finish your program.
This is a code of sub, which gives you HTML Code of web-pages:

Function GetHTMLCode(strURL As String) As String 
    Dim objHttp As Object, strText As String 
    Set objHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") 
    objHttp.Open "GET", strURL, False 
    objHttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", _ 
        "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)" 
    objHttp.Send ("") 
    strText = objHttp.responseText 
    Set objHttp = Nothing 
    GetHTMLCode = strText 
End Function

I have found that all the links of pictures in Google Pictures are starting with this HTML code : 
src="http:// 
and end with this :  
" 
The links of pictures are between these 2 lines!!!  
You can use GetHTMLCode to get all HTML code of current web page. 
Then continually find these 2 lines using "instr" function , and download the links between them. 
Problem Solved!

Please vote , if my answer is useful :)